# Make read-only directory accessible to other users

Tags: files, permissions, samba, gvfs

I have mounted a read-only share via gvfs-mount to `/run/user/60373/gvfs/smb-share`. I would like to make other users read this share. The problem is that I can't set the permissions recursively as I only have the right to read the directory `smb-share`, but not to write to it.
I don't have root rights.

Comment: Have you asked the system administrator to do this?

Comment: I asked some time ago and they suggested a workaround: copy all the content to my local HD, and change the rights there. Not really elegant...

Comment: Not a client-friendly solution too.